# Would or will which is more fit?

Tags: word-usage, modal-verbs

I wrote the following sentence:

> In our village, there is a man that would/will help anybody in need.

I want to say that helping people is a characteristic or the habit of that man so I tried to use would or will yet I wonder  which one is more fit would or will in this simple present tense?

Also, is there any difference if we omit would or will altogether?

> In our village,there is a man that helps anybody in need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a man in our village that helps anybody in need
 and
There is a man in our village that will help any body in need mean the same thing.
 It says that it is his(the man in your village) habit  to help the needy
 but you can not say There is a man in our village that would help any body in need because the sequence of the tense is wrong.

you may say there was a man in our village that would help anybody in need
 but the meaning changes.It means that the man is no longer there and he used to help the needy in the past

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I am looking for.